Tailwind CSS IntelliSense Not Working (Server crash)
I had the Tailwind CSS IntelliSense plugin for a while and it was working fine, but as of today it keeps showing this error:

"The Tailwind CSS IntelliSense server crashed 5 times in the last 3 minutes. The server will not be restarted. See the output for more information."
I tried uninstalling and reinstalling it but it's still not working, Does anyone know what this error is?
